# Weblogic server start failure

Tags: java, weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic11g, java-server

I working with weblogc 12.1.2 server

I try to start server using `nohup sh startWeblogic.sh &` cammand

It gives below error.

```
Starting WLS with line:
/opt/OracleJDK_WebLogic/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java -server   -Xms1024m -Xmx1024m -Dweblogic.Name=AdminServer -Djava.security.policy=/home/epic/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.policy  -Xverify:none -Djava.system.class.loader=com.oracle.classloader.weblogic.LaunchClassLoader  -javaagent:/home/epic/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server/lib/debugpatch-agent.jar -da -Dwls.home=/home/epic/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server -Dweblogic.home=/home/epic/Oracle/Middleware/Oracle_Home/wlserver/server  -Duser.timezone=UTC    weblogic.Server
./startWebLogic.sh: line 187: 19111 Killed ${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java ${JAVA_VM} ${MEM_ARGS} -Dweblogic.Name=${SERVER_NAME} -Djava.security.policy=${WLS_POLICY_FILE} ${JAVA_OPTIONS} ${PROXY_SETTINGS} ${SERVER_CLASS}
```

Is any one can describe how to fix this issue. it will be great helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

From this information, the startup script will actively kill the current Weblogic process. But from the information you provided, you can't see whether the process started successfully. You are also required to provide the following relevant information to facilitate our further analysis and positioning:

1. Please provide the startup script file startWebLogic.sh.
2. Please provide the startup log file $domain / services / adminserver / logs/ AdminServer.log.
3. Provide startup log nohup.out file.